# Visual Studio 2012: different color themes for different projects

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have two Visual Studio instances with two opened "the same" projects. The difference is the projects are from different branches. Is there a way to make Visual Studio instances' appearance different from each other depends on project? There are plenty posts about Color Theme Editor extension, but it changes theme for all instances.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried [VSCommands](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a83505c6-77b3-44a6-b53b-73d77cba84c8) extension from Visual Studio Gallerty ?
It has feature called [Solution Badges](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/features#solutionbadge) which may help you.

[image: Solution Badges]

Comment: This is great extension! It helped me a lot. Unfortunately, it cannot change color theme — just title, icon, and thumbnail in Windows Task Switcher. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @Evgeni Nabokov, I believe that changing theme affects all opened Visual Studio instances, so at the moment it is not possible to have two instances using different themes.

Comment: Thank you for this really, great practice for users like me using multiple instances.

Comment: Doesn't have version for VS 2017. Also , doesn't seem to be maintained anymore.

Answer (score 6):

One option is to launch visual studio from the command line (or custom shortcuts) with the /rootsuffix argument. This forces VS to create a fresh node in the registry for all your VS settings, and on subsequent runs, with the settings saved under the provided node.

For example, I have two enlistments on a single machine, and I can open two instances of VS as follows:
d:\source\green> devenv /rootsuffix green
d:\source\red> devenv /rootsuffix red

One downside of this option is you will have to reconfigure all your preferences (font/colors, document formatting, symbol settings, addons and extensions, etc.) I recommend launching the default VS instance and exporting all your preferences (tools > import and export settings) to an xml file so you can import them from each of your new devenv nodes. You'll still need to manually reconfigure some other things, mainly addons.

As for customizing VS theme colors for each rootsuffix, I recommend Visual Studio 2013 Color Theme Editor (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9e08e5d3-6eb4-4e73-a045-6ea2a5cbdabe?SRC=VSIDE). As mentioned above, you'll need to install this once for each rootsuffix you create since extension information is stored on a per-rootsuffix basis in the registry.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to share an extension that did the trick for me. I tried this in VS2015.

The extension name is: [SolutionColor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Wumpf.SolutionColor#review-details)

All I wanted was some visual distinction between my Main and Dev branch when both are opened at a same time. With this extension I could set the title of VS to a specific color and that was plenty for me!

Comment: The FAQ of that extension says "Only the filename of the active sln is used to distinguish between projects.". I suppose both Main and Dev branches have the same solution name, so they would end up having the same color??

Comment: No its not based on the filename, or if it is may be its on the full file path. Anyways, it works - it displays my main and dev in two different colors.